# ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets why can't I use the value from the cell above for calculations?

Tags: google-sheets

I've been plucking at this thing for a few days now and I just don't understand it at all!

I have a checkbook ledger that I really don't want to copy the formula when I run out of rows.  Rather have the formula advance as rows are needed.

Here's an editable version that I'm testing with Sheet2 is the current victim:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k0vdtAtK2QpdHsSfN0re30BV2BhJM08GQVjbzuumoGg/edit?usp=sharing

In the short the formula should use the cell above (balance) and then subtract the debit column and add the credit column thus giving the balance again.  Rinse and repeat after that.

So I'm at this impasse where it isn't going to work because it's not supposed to or I'm just going to have to deal and copy the formula(s) down the page when needed.

I'm not lazy .. just trying to be efficient!

Answer (score 1):

A formula cannot refer to its own output, so an iterative calculation with arrayformula doesn't seem possible. One can use a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) for this effect: for example, in E3 enter

```
=balance(E2, B3:B, C3:C)
```

where E2 is the initial amount, B3:B is the debit column and C3:C is the credit column. The function source code is

```
function balance(initial, debit, credit) {
  var bal = initial;
  var out = [];
  for (i in debit) {
    bal = bal - debit[i][0] + credit[i][0];
    out.push([bal]);
  }
  return out;  
}
```